# How do I use Windows 10 built-in package manager?

Tags: windows-10, package-management, windows-packagemanagement

I'm finding Windows 10 package management not very intuitive. Below are my adventures in trying to install VLC, which sounds like a very common test case for a package manager.

```
Find-Package vlc
```

Nope

```
Find-Package -Update
```

Nope

```
Install-Package --help
```

Nope

```
Install-Package /?
```

Nope

```
Install-Package vlc

The provider 'nuget v2.8.5.127' is not installed.
nuget may be manually downloaded from https://oneget.org/nuget-anycpu-2.8.5.127.exe and installed.
Would you like PackageManagement to automatically download and install 'nuget' now?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'vlc'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package vlc
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Ex
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

Nope

```
Register-PackageSource -Name chocolatey -Location http://chocolatey.org/api/v2 -Provider PSModule -Trusted -Verbose
```

Maybe?

```
Install-Package vlc
WARNING: The module 'vlc' cannot be installed or updated because it is not a properly-formed module.
```

Nope

Comment: Try [`Install-Package -Name VLC`](http://www.howtogeek.com/200334/windows-10-includes-a-linux-style-package-manager-named-oneget/).

Comment: `Install-Package -Name VLC`
`Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'VLC'.`

Comment: Does `Find-Package -Name VLC` find anything for you? Also, check if it's case sensitive.

Comment: `Find-Package -Name VLC`
Find-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'VLC'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Find-Package -Name VLC
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...ets.FindPackage:FindPackage) [Find-Package], Exceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.FindPackage

Comment: So I played around with it some more. I got the same error you did for VLC but installing `putty` worked. Not sure who's side the problem is on now.

Comment: I'm having similar problems with `iojs`. It *finds* the package just fine, but when I try to install it, it says its not found.

Comment: `help Install-Package` works.

Comment: You might wanna do a `update-help` first.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using Windows' commands rather than chocolatey directly for package that come from the chocolatey repo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were close. First, you have to set the execution policy to allow scripts, otherwise it'll silently fail while reporting success ([bug](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/97#issuecomment-139331418)):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Both the package provider (Chocolatey plugin) and package source (URL to specific Chocolatey repo) need to be installed/registered with PackageManagement. Get-PackageProvider with the `-Force` flag causes it to bootstrap, which apparently takes care of both (more in the help about `-Force`):

```
Get-PackageProvider Chocolatey -Force | Out-Null
```

Then I can search for the package:

```
Find-Package vlc -Force

Name       Version          Source           Summary
----       -------          ------           -------
vlc        2.2.1.20150630   chocolatey       VLC Media Player
```

And install it (`-Force` so it doesn't prompt for confirmation):

```
Install-Package vlc -Force | Out-Null
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me on a clean Windows 10 RTM, it just puts everything in C:\Chocolatey\lib but doesn't actually install the programs or run the scripts required to do so.

Comment: Oh, there's a [terribly confusing bug](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/97#issuecomment-139331418) in PackageManagement where that exact behavior happens unless, before installing packages, you set the execution policy to allow scripts (I use RemoteSigned). I'll update my answer.

Comment: Great to hear. Hopefully they'll get these wrinkles ironed out. Don't forget to mark the answer if you like :-)

Comment: How would I install multiple packages in one line? That's the industry standard for all package managers. It appears I get an error if I run `Install-Package vlc firefox -Force`

Comment: @JonathanLeaders, just put commas between the package names.

Comment: @JVimes This doesn't seem to work anymore. The error is similar to RedShift. If execution policy is set to `RemoteSigned` the script errors out with `The system cannot find...` ; if you reset the execution policty with `Set-ExecutionPolicy Default` it doesn't error out but nothing is installed into Program files. The installers are correctly deposited in `C:\Chocolatey\lib`

Comment: @xenithorb, I confirm what you're seeing. I had so many problems with the Chocolatey provider I gave up on it long ago. Looks its GitHub page is [here](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey-oneget).