# Programs installed via OneGet doesn't show up

Tags: windows-10, windows-packagemanagement

I followed this [guide](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AptGetForWindowsOneGetAndChocolateyOnWindows10.aspx) to install VLC via OneGet.
However VLC doesn't show up in the start menu or in the "Add or remove program" after it has been successfully installed.

What am I doing wrong?

[image] [image]

**Commands**

```
PS C:\Users\Snebjorn> get-packageprovider -name chocolatey

The provider 'chocolatey v2.8.5.130' is not installed.
chocolatey may be manually downloaded from https://oneget.org/ChocolateyPrototype-2.8.5.130.exe and installed.
Would you like PackageManagement to automatically download and install 'chocolatey' now?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):

Name                     Version          DynamicOptions
----                     -------          --------------
Chocolatey               2.8.5.130        {SkipDependencies, ContinueOnFailure, ExcludeVersion, ForceX86...}


PS C:\Users\Snebjorn> install-package vlc

The provider 'nuget v2.8.5.127' is not installed.
nuget may be manually downloaded from https://oneget.org/nuget-anycpu-2.8.5.127.exe and installed.
Would you like PackageManagement to automatically download and install 'nuget' now?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):

The package(s) come from a package source that is not marked as trusted.
Are you sure you want to install software from 'chocolatey'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): y

Name                           Version          Source           Summary
----                           -------          ------           -------
vlc                            2.2.1.20150630   chocolatey       VLC Media Player


PS C:\Users\Snebjorn>
```

Comment: run processmonitor in background while installing VLC and look where the files are written to.

Comment: I'm not familiar with processmonitor. How do I open it?

Comment: Microsoft explained the tool in 2 videos: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor, https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer as comment on this post [How do I use Windows 10 built-in package manager?](https://superuser.com/questions/957712/how-do-i-use-windows-10-built-in-package-manager)

> Oh, there's a terribly confusing bug in PackageManagement where that
>   exact behavior happens unless, before installing packages, you set the
>   execution policy to allow scripts (I use RemoteSigned). I'll update my
>   answer.

So after running `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` and reinstalling VLC it works as expected. Yay!